# how to replace/customize back button image in storyboard navigationcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I want to replace the text in the back button with a custom image.  How can I do that in swift code?  I don't want to replace the entire backbarbutton since I'd like to keep the default action behaviour of going back to the last view.  I would also like to do a switch statement based on where the back destination(based on storyboardId) is so that I can show different images based on the view.

this replaces the image but it wipes out the default back button behavior, and I need to discrimante on what the back destination is so that I can show the right back image.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = 
 UIBarButtonItem(image:StyleKit.imageOfMap, style:.Plain, target:self, action:nil);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try changing your `leftBarButtonItem`:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = 
    UIBarButtonItem(image:StyleKit.imageOfMap, style:.Plain, target:self, action:nil);
```

to a `backBarButtonItem`:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = 
    UIBarButtonItem(image:StyleKit.imageOfMap, style:.Plain, target:self, action:nil);
```

in order to take advantage of `backBarButtonItem`'s default action.

And put that line of code in the view controller *preceding* the one you'd like your custom back button to appear in.

**Edit**: If you don't want the "<" symbol to appear on your button, you'll have to in fact use a `leftBarButtonItem` then dismiss the view controller in a separate method, ex:

```
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = 
        UIBarButtonItem(image:StyleKit.imageOfMap, style:.Plain, target:self, action:"backButtonPressed:");

}

func backButtonPressed(sender:UIButton) {
    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Comment: Oh cool that almost works, 2 questions: how do I get rid of the default < symbol, and why does it need to be added in the previous controller?

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey I don't really know why you need to set the back button in the previous controller, but that's the way it is... You can't get rid of the < symbol on the back button unfortunately though. You'll have to do a leftBarButtonItem if you want to get rid of the < symbol then call a custom method to dismiss the view controller. I'll update my answer to show you how to do that... one sec...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];    
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOURIMAGE.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(youraction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn]autorelease];
```