# Editing the navigation controller from push segue

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, swift2, segue, uistoryboardsegue

So i have a static tableview with 4 rows, i'm connecting them to different viewcontrollers without using any code instead i'm simply dragging the cell and setting up the segue.

The issue i'm having is that when this segue is performed a navigation controller is automatically generated and embed at the top so i get the following result below.

[image: View with default icon and text]

How could i edit the text and the icon? I want to remove the settings text and use my own custom icon.

It's also worth noting that i have embed other navigation controllers throughout my app. So i'd like to target this view specifically rather than all of my views.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the accepted answer on this question may help: [how to replace/customize back button image in storyboard navigationcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421769/how-to-replace-customize-back-button-image-in-storyboard-navigationcontroller)

You'll need to do it in your prepareForSegue I believe.