# Swift 2 - How do I customise the navigation controller back button to a custom button?

Tags: xcode, swift, navigation, viewcontroller, navigationcontroller

I am currently working on a project and when I switch to a ViewController, the back button appears at the top left, how do I set the back button so that it is customised with a custom button of my choice? Ideally I do not want the back button appearing at the top but I want it associated with a separate button when reverting back to the previous ViewController.

Comment: See if the following Q&A can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421769/how-to-replace-customize-back-button-image-in-storyboard-navigationcontroller

Comment: @dfri I've had a look at the link that you provided and it does not seek to help with the problem I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not show the back button at the top just hide it.

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

And then just implement popViewControllerAnimated in your custom button action.

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: I have got this working partially, I have embedded the ViewController in Navigation Controller, the next view is ViewController2 that displays my content i.e. image, the view after this is ViewController3 and its at ViewController3 that I have inputed the code you provided, when I click the custom back button, it reverts back to ViewController and not back to ViewController2. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Sounds like you are using popToRootViewControllerAnimated.   Are you sure you are implementing popViewControllerAnimated and not popToRootViewControllerAnimated??

Comment: I'm using popViewControllerAnimated in your answer.

Comment: Fixed the problem, just had to remove a triggered segue.